# Flutter Doctor - Unable to determine bundled Java version

Tags: flutter, mobile, android-sdk-2.3

I actually didn't want to install Android Studio to use flutter, so i just installed the Android SDK Command Line Tools.

The thing is, when i run flutter doctor i get the following warning.

[image: Running flutter doctor]

And when i create a new project i get this one.

[image]

I am able to create and compile flutter projects without any issues, it is only the warning that worries me. Could it cause dependency trouble in the future for java related packages?

Answer (score 20):

Execute these commands one by one and it resolved my issue in MAC .

cd  /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

Comment: thanks, that made it.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Resolved the problem thanks, could you explain what these commands does?

Comment: thanks, after hours struggling with this issue, this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 7):

Please ensure Java is in your `PATH` and that `JAVA_HOME` is defined and pointing to the `JDK`. I've had Windows put the `JRE` in the path instead of the JDK, which leads to all kinds of issues.

Please take a look at your `PATH environment variable` and remove everything Java related that does not point to the `JDK folder`.

Oracle has some documentation on how to do this here : [Installing Java and setting JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html).

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: You have last version?

Comment: Previously i was using OpenJDK 13, but it wasn't compatible with Android SDK and wouldn't let me install it because java issues. Currently i switched to JDK 8u202 and it works just fine.

Comment: facing the same issue. I install jdk8 32 bit as it didn't worked with 64 bit and pointed %JAVA_HOME% to 32bit now.. But so far no luck

Comment: Thanks. This solved it for me. I had an old version saved in JAVA_HOME (11.0.10), while i had 11.0.13 on my machine.
Also, notice that you have to close and reopen the shell in order for the new env variable to be read.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, I had 2 versions of Android studio. And I removed one. So there might be a possibility that you have an older/another version of Android Studio present in your machine.