# X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\bin\java to determine the version

Tags: flutter

```
  [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\jan03\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\server\bin\java
    X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\server\bin\java to determine the version
```

[image]

- java version :- 16.0 jdk
- android studio version :- 4.2.1
- flutter version:- 2.2.1

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048148/15106159

Answer (score 3):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`, then copy the contents of jbr and paste the contents into the jre folder.
It solve both problem

- Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\bin\java to determine the version
- unable to find bundled java version

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot!

Why is it happening? Very strange problem right at the beginning.

Comment: I don't remember now. Face this issue long time ago

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the JDK path to the system environment variable from your device. Please follow the instruction given for setting the path. Please don't use Java_home or any small letter. follow the instruction strictly. And also don't need to put variable location till bin.

1. Go to System variable
2. create a new variable called `JAVA_HOME`
3. Variable value as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2`
4. Go to system variable name PATH
   5.Click to edit and add a new variable call `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

If not understood please follow: https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

## USE SAME ANDROID STUDIO JAVA VERSION

### (windows) INTRODUCTION

1. the java version found at path

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

2. we need to edit enviroment variable of "JAVA_HOME" to be equal "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr"
   you can set from cmd by open as adminstartor, then write this command:

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr"
```

3. test by echo the JAVA_HOME from cmd

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

4- Restart Android Studio, then call this command from termnial.

- example the default android studio sdk found at path"C:\Users\abdo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" so we need to config the android directory by cmd :

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir C:\Users\abdo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
```

then

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```